# R example for selecting rows based on certain criterion

Tags: r

I have written a R code. Please let me know if there is a better way of doing things (which I am sure of, as my code sucks). The data has three rows, called SIC, FYEAR, and SALES. I want to choose only those entries from data where the number of rows for which SIC, and FYEAR are same is greater than 7. The data looks like this:

```
    SIC FYEAR     SALE
1   50  2003  651.958
2   50  2004  747.848
3   50  2005  897.284
4   50  2006 1061.169
5   50  2007 1384.919
6   50  2008 1423.976
7   50  2009 1352.151
8   50  2010 1775.782
9   50  2011 2074.498
10  50  2012 2167.100
11  36  2003  773.200
12  36  2004  784.300
13  36  2005 1169.200
14  36  2006 1281.900
15  36  2007 1322.200
16  36  2008 1456.400
17  36  2009  996.700
18  36  2010 1156.600
19  38  2003   18.044
20  38  2004   19.833 ...
```

Apply doing the following operation,

```
a <- ddply(data, .(SIC,FYEAR), function(x){length(x$SALE)});
```

a looks like

```
SIC FYEAR V1
1    1  2003 16
2    1  2004 13
3    1  2005 13
4    1  2006 11
5    1  2007 11
6    1  2008 12
7    1  2009 14
8    1  2010 17
9    1  2011 16
10   1  2012 20
11   1  2013  5
12   2  2003  2
13   2  2004  2
14   2  2005  2
15   2  2006  2
16   2  2007  3
17   2  2008  4
18   2  2009  4
19   2  2010  5
20   2  2011  3 ...
```

which says that in the original data there were 16 rows with SIC 1 and FYEAR 2003. Then I select those SIC, FYEAR pair for which V1 >=8.

```
a <- sqldf("select SIC, FYEAR from a where V1 >=8");
```

In the end, I merge data and a to get rows for only those SIC, FYEAR pair where #rows were greater or equal to 8. Following line does the trick.

```
data <- merge(a, data, by= c("SIC","FYEAR"));
```

data looks like this now:

```
   SIC FYEAR V1     SALE
1    1  2003 16   15.426
2    1  2003 16  338.272
3    1  2003 16    8.433
4    1  2003 16 4936.000
5    1  2003 16  477.405
6    1  2003 16  129.781
7    1  2003 16    0.000
8    1  2003 16 2613.548
9    1  2003 16   26.356
10   1  2003 16   94.988
11   1  2003 16   96.452
12   1  2003 16   18.343
13   1  2003 16 4773.141
14   1  2003 16  281.276
15   1  2003 16 2486.800
16   1  2003 16   48.285
17   1  2004 13   23.624
18   1  2004 13 5457.000
19   1  2004 13   36.431
20   1  2004 13   74.045 ...
```

Is there a better way to do the same thing, which I have done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using `plyr`, you can just do:

```
ddply(data, .(SIC,FYEAR), function(x) if (nrow(x) > 7) x else NULL)
```